# How to insert array into crate?

Tags: php, pdo, crate

How do I insert an array into crate?

I'm using the latest Crate-PDO, but keep receiving this notice

> Notice: Array to string conversion in .../Crate/PDO/PDOStatement.php on line 610

and

> Array to string conversion in .../myPdoClass.php on line 118

I'm using this code:

```
$myArray = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];

$db = new Database;
$db->Query("insert into tbl (id, arrayCol) values (?,?)");
$db->bind(1, '1');
$db->bind(2, $myArray); 
$db->execute();
```

Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: Because you are giving an array as parameter of the second bind() call. Bind expect a string.

Answer (score 2):

To bind any non-string parameter you must use the PDO bindValue() method passing in the wanted type as the 3rd parameter. Example:

```
$statement->bindValue(2, [1, 2], PDO::PARAM_ARRAY)
```

Comment: I've tried this, however I then get " Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'PARAM_ARRAY' in"

Comment: either import the crate pdo namespace, like: `use Crate\PDO\PDO` or use the FQ classname: Crate\PDO\PDO::PARAM_ARRAY

Comment: I've adding this, require ("../../../vendor/crate/crate-do/src/Crate/PDO/PDO.php");use Crate\PDO\PDO; To myPdoClass.php and i still get 'Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'PARAM_ARRAY' in'

Comment: have you tried using the FQ classname? btw. this is the test at crate-pdo validating the array type support: https://github.com/crate/crate-pdo/blob/master/test/CrateIntegrationTest/PDO/PDOStatementTest.php#L253

Comment: this is the correct solution," either import the crate pdo namespace, like: use Crate\PDO\PDO or use the FQ classname: Crate\PDO\PDO::PARAM_ARRAY " from @sebastian many thanks

Answer (score -1):

*EDIT : This a quick fix for the given error, not a way to store arrays.*

You have to explicitly convert your array to a string. A simple way to do this :

```
$myString = "[" + implode(", ", $myArray) + "]";
```

That will give you the string `"[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]"`

It's an example but you got the idea.

[Documentation about implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: Yeah, but it won't be saved as an array. So you it's more complicated to get it back.

Comment: You can't just store an array in a MySql databse. You have to push it as string. That syntax here is JSON syntax. You can Use php Json functions for more simple use

Comment: this will not save the array as an array, this is not the answer to the question

Comment: hey guys, this is not about MySQL, please read the question again. believe me or not, other databases than MySQL do really exist ;)

Comment: I honestly think @EmrysMyrooin knows that, too. I just wanted to point out this answer. That doesn't mean we don't know there are other DBs, it just means we correct each other so other will benefit from that and thats what this platform is here for, not? So, Sebastian Utz and Emrys Myrooin thank you for sharing your knowledge with me. ;)

Comment: @Sebastian Utz Yes I haven't right understood what he was asking. Thanks for the corection.

Comment: It is a DB that allows arrays to be inserted, just the PDO class i'm using seems like its missing something. Thanks though.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't worked with Crate, but I would do something like this:

```
$myArray = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
$myArrayEncoded = json_encode($myArray);

$db = new Database;
$db->Query("insert into tbl (id, arrayCol) values (?,?)");
$db->bind(1, '1');
$db->bind(2, $myArrayEncoded); 
$db->execute();
```

When you later retrieve it from the Database and want to have it back like it is on the first line, you decode it:

```
$myArrayDecoded = json_decode($myArrayEncoded);
```

Maybe there are better solutions from people who actually worked with it, but I am pretty sure, this should work too!

Comment: this will not make use of the array type, this is not the answer to the question

Comment: As I said it in my answer, I've never worked with it and this is just a workaround. It should work, so IMO need to give -1! So, if you have a better solution, then just post it! (As you did! So thank you for correcting it!)

Comment: Its a DB that allows array to be inserted, thanks though.

Answer (score -3):

use

```
$statement->bindValue(2, [1, 2], PDO::PARAM_ARRAY)
```

Comment: this will not make use of the array type, please think about the question before answering!